# iis specify doctype

Tags: asp.net, iis, doctype

I have an ASP .Net page that, in my localhost and in the office testing environment is displaying in transitional mode, as specified by Visual Studio, but at customer testing environment it's displaying as Strict mode. I see this same behavior in other pages of other websites hosted in the customer testing environment. So, the question is: Is it possible to tell IIS to render pages in the mode I publish the page???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the DOCTYPE settings you're using in your pages?  Are you using Master Pages?  It will be easier to get the answer that you need if you can provide a little bit more about your situation.

Comment: Visual Studio defaults to <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> but when I saw IIS was serving <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">, I decided to put strict on visual studio. I'm using ASP Net 3.5 Web Forms

Comment: The doctype setting in the master or aspx page should override anything set in IIS.  Can you verify that your pages do have the "Traditional" doctype setting?  Is it possible that no doctype was originally included, allowing IIS to default to "strict"?

Answer (score 1):

The `DOCTYPE` is defined in your `.ASPXs` or your `.master` files being used.  Either the page or your master page is different at the client site and hopefully not this, but it may not be defined at all, which lets the browser decide what to do.

Comment: Hi @rick-schott I'm using Master pages, so the doctype is declared in the master page. I'm see the page is served as strict because I right cliek the page and see the view source